# Show that $ e^{\overline{i\theta}} = \overline{e^{i\theta}}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to show that

$$ n^{-\overline{s}} = \overline{n^{-s}}$$

for complex $s$ and integer $n$.

A simpler challenge is to show that

$$ e^{\overline{i\theta}} = \overline{e^{i\theta}}$$

I am struggling to show this, even thought I feel it should be obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are assuming that $\theta$ is real:

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta.$$
$$\overline{e^{i\theta}} = \cos \theta - i\sin \theta 
= e^{-i\theta}=e^{\overline{i \theta}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $-s = x + iy$, and therefore $-\overline{s} = x - iy$. Then $n^{-s} = n^x n^{iy} = a+ib$, and $n^{-\overline{s}} = n^x n^{-iy}= c+id$ for some $a,b,c,d$, as the exponential forms must also be complex numbers. Now we can say:

$$n^{- \overline{s}} = \overline{n^{-s}} \iff a = c \land b = -d \tag{1}$$

Now consider that $n^{iy} = e^{iy \log n} = \cos (y \log n) + i \sin(y \log n)$. I'm going to substitute $y \log n = q$ for speed. That means that $n^{-s} = a+ib = n^x \cos q + in^x \sin q$, and $n^{-\overline{s}} = c+id = n^x \cos q - in^x \sin q$. Those together imply $a = c (= n^x \cos q)$, and $b = -d (= in^x \sin q)$, which is the RHS of $(1)$. Therefore the LHS of (1) holds.